# Server recieves empty object from multer fetch post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, fetch-api

I'm trying to set up a form on this webpage that sends a file to my Node server without leaving the page the form is on. I have mutler listening for file uploads, and I think I've set up the fileStorageEngine properly. The client-side JS is seeing the right file, and presumably sending it, but the server is only getting an empty object. I'm sure there's something I've done wrong in the fetch request or the mutler setup, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

**The form's HTML**

```html
<form id="file-selection" action="/files" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="tcg-original" accept=".csv" name="givenFilename"></input>
    <input type="submit" id="start-button" value="Start"></input>
</form>
```

**The function called when the start button is clicked**

```js
function process(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = document.getElementById("file-selection");
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    fetch(form.action, {method: form.method, body: form.body});
}
```

**The server JS file**

```js
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";

const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening at 3000"));
app.use(express.static("site"));
app.use(express.json({limit: "100mb"}));

const fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "uploads");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, "uploadedFile");
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: fileStorageEngine });

app.post("/files", upload.single("givenFilename"), (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);
    console.log(request.file);
});
```

Comment: There are a few simple things wrong. 1. input is a self closing tag so `</input>` is not needed. 2. You're creating `formData` but not sending it with your request.